# How can I use a foreign key while I'm working to online Server

Tags: mariadb

I  am trying to insert a primary key of my product [ https://www.irezon.com/irezon_main_files/Buy_Our_Strong_System.php ]  to a table which contain the information of clients [ https://www.irezon.com/buy_system/Step_1_of_2.php?id=9 ] using MariaDb but  I failed. Someone can guide me on which steps to follow please!

Comment: "failed" == crashed system?  Gave error message, if so, what?  Gave warning?  Inserted blanks?  Null?  Give us some clues.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please edit your question to include your code in case it's causing the issue. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for reference

Comment: My tables CREATE TABLE `product_1` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `project_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `we_used` varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
  `descrp` varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
  `launch` varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
  `developed_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `request1` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `country_in` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `typ` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `why_this` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `expl` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Systembought` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;